# Why is IEX Finance not loading/working and not recognizing the module?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, finance, elixir-iex

So I have iexfinance - I successfully installed it via PIP, obtained an API token, etc but whenever I try running I get the following error:

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'iexfinance'

Here is the code:

```
from iexfinance import IexFinance as iex

aapl = iex("AAPL")
aapl.get_quote()
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: It might be an environment or pip issue. Check pip list.

Comment: @SiddharthDas Thanks - I checked, it's there

C:\Users\Danny>pip list
Package                Version
---------------------- -----------
absl-py                0.9.0
appdirs                1.4.3
astunparse             1.6.3
cachetools             4.1.0
certifi                2020.4.5.1
chardet                3.0.4
gast                   0.3.3
google-auth            1.14.1
google-auth-oauthlib   0.4.1
google-pasta           0.2.0
grpcio                 1.28.1
h5py                   2.10.0
idna                   2.9
iexfinance             0.4.3

Comment: If you are using python3 then mostly you need to use pip3. Are you using any environment?